# Use a shell script to consume a message from Kafka to check service availability. What should I do best?

Tags: shell, apache-kafka

I have 100 servers with Kafka deployed on some of the hosts, and the kafka service is started by the kafka user. I want to use a shell script to find out the kafka machine and consume a message to ensure that the service is available.

Answer (score 0):

> Find out the Kafka machine

I'm not sure what this means

> ensure that the service is available.

Ideally, you'd use something like Nagios or Consul for this, not a consumer. Otherwise, `kcat -L` or `kcat -C` are two popular CLI ways to check/consume from brokers that doesnt require extra dependencies.

Beyond that, your commands wouldn't be checking a specific broker, only the cluster

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used Grafana monitoring. kcat is not easy to install.

Comment: Unless you're trying to compile it, it's one line to install https://github.com/edenhill/kcat#install